# dynamic_decode throws ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a pretty simple seq2seq model and I keep getting weird error. The model I am building is similar to https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt.

I keep getting ValueError at the decoding stage

```html
lstm_dec = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(nodes)

helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(
    output_embed, output_len, time_major=False, name = "trainHelper"
)

projLayer = tf.layers.Dense(DICTIONARY_SIZE, name="projection_layer")

# Decoder
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
    lstm_dec,
    helper,
    last_state
)

# Dynamic decoding
outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder)

logits = projLayer(outputs.rnn_output)
```

Error looks like this:

```html
ValueError: Could not flatten dictionary. Key had 2 elements, but value had 1 elements. Key: [<tf.Tensor 'decoding/decoder/transpose:0' shape=(70, ?, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'decoding/decoder/transpose_1:0' shape=(70, ?) dtype=int32>]
```

This is happening when I do dynamic_decode()
Just in case - my batch_size is 70 and nodes=128

Did anyone else encounter similar issue?

Thanks!